# how to store multiple objects in flex sharedlocalobject?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a project where the client can save data from a flex app to their client in xml , something like

`<xml>`
`<project id='1111'>`
`<data ... />`
`<data ... />`
`</project>`
`</xml>`

this is stored on the flex sharedlocalobject , but if the client creates a new project it overwrites the existing project. How can i store multiple projects in the sharedlocalobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` attribute of a shared object can store arbitrary number of values like this:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("sharedObject");
so.data.one = 1;
so.data.two = 2;
...
```

So in your case, you could simply store each project XML in a separate "attribute" of the data object.